# Would the dle 55ra engine be enough to power my paramotor(ducted fan)?

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller, engine, thrust

I plan on using the dle 55ra engine to produce 5hp at 8,500 rpm. I am using it in a paramotor, and to save space I am considering using a ducted propeller similar to the Fulcrum power pod. The duct intake would have to be directly behind my back, so I plan to add around 6 inches of space to allow air intake. The engine would be mounted on my back facing into the intake. Effectively, it would be a normal paramotor with a duct around the fan blades. My estimated duct wall clearance is 1 or less mm. I need to produce 15kg of thrust, so how would I design this fan? I considered using a [heating duct](https://www.theductshop.com/shop/18-x-16-reducer-p-246.html), which is an 18-16 reducer. This would allow me to get some benefits of the thrust tube and would make it easy to have a front-mounted propeller. Would [this propeller](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-beech-wood-propeller-18x7-1pc.html?wrh_pdp=2&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=google_us_shopping&countrycode=US&gclid=Cj0KCQiA4aacBhCUARIsAI55maELKVgKc3jOLjANvowxWHrGUqDYLgC3fJgoJLjTxL3Lg0aTpBrUH-gaAvrJEALw_wcB) work? It is 18x7"

**TLDR: Would my combination of [propeller](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-beech-wood-propeller-18x7-1pc.html?wrh_pdp=2&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=google_us_shopping&countrycode=US&gclid=Cj0KCQiA4aacBhCUARIsAI55maELKVgKc3jOLjANvowxWHrGUqDYLgC3fJgoJLjTxL3Lg0aTpBrUH-gaAvrJEALw_wcB), [duct](https://www.theductshop.com/shop/18-x-16-reducer-p-246.html) and [engine](https://www.horizonhobby.com/product/dle-55ra-gas-rear-exhaust-with-electronic-ignition/DLEG0455.html) produce 15kg of thrust.**

Thank you!

Comment: Paramotors require at minimum 125lbs of thrust to have any kind of performance for climb. Most are around 140-175 lbs. 35lbs won't even get you off the ground.

Comment: @GregHewgill  It's a paramotor question. Paramotors are airplanes.

Comment: @John K, I don’t think I mentioned this in the question, however in a separate post other users helped me calculate that 5hp was enough to get 82kg full weight in the air, with some extra leftover.p(~2.5 extra hp). If my wing has a glide ratio of 7:1, then 82/7= 11.7143kg required for level flight. The approximately 3kg of thrust left would be for climbing. Would I need more? 20kg of thrust in total would probably be good.

Comment: +Lelotz I already factored in climb ratio, as me and my  setup weighs 64kg now, and I am accounting for future weight gain. 64/7=9.1429, so 15 is more than enough

Comment: You will need WAAAAAY more.  This harness/power pod appears to be exactly what you are shooting for:   https://www.fulcrum-engines.com/.  Its engine is 25HP to make 110 lbs thrust, about the absolute minimum.  110lbs is not much for 25 hp, ducted fans being somewhat inefficient.  Regular PMs make 150-170 lbs with the same engine using a large prop and reduction drive. That's the price paid for the ducted fan.

Comment: @JohnK: My apologies, I did not read the question carefully enough.

Comment: @John K. Why would I need so much thrust? I do not weigh that much and at min 25kg is probably the best solution. I average a bunch of paramotors together, their thrust/max weight and got an approximate value of 0.35. 25/82 is 0.3 and they are not far apart. 170 lbs is enough to make me hover and climb quickly

Comment: Well, about the smallest paramotor you can get is the Atom 80, which makes 120lbs thr with a large prop and belt drive. That's about the bottom end, meant for girls and very light males.  You need the thrust to be able to escape from bad situations close to the ground when your airplane is so hypersensitive to air movements close to the surface.